# Changing an instance description in google cloud

Tags: cloud, gcloud

If you do:

`gcloud compute instances list--format=flattened`

There is a field called `description`. I would love to be able to add descriptions to my instances and then be able to display them when I list them.

How do I add descriptions via the command gcloud? How about the console? (I can't find it either way).

Answer (score 1):

When creating an instance with `gcloud` tool you can pass `--description` flag to give it the description you want.

When creating an instance using web UI you can click "Management, disks, networking, SSH keys" link at bottom of the page, then you will see a field where you can enter the description (in "Management" section).

You can also use instance insert [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/insert) to add description to the instance while creating one.

Changing description after you create an instant seems impossible at the moment.